# Chomsky Hierarchy Type 2: Not terminal symbols on left hand site

Tags: chomsky-hierarchy

is it allowed to make two non terminal symbols on the left handed side of a grammatic in type 2 grammatic?

[image]

I should define a Type 2 grammatic for the Language L2. It was easy if it is allowed to do a rule like

CB->BC but I'm not sure if this would violate any rules. In Type 1 it'd be easy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. According to the *Chomsky Hierarchy*, a Type-2 Language is characterized by rules in the form `$A \rightarrow a$` where `$A$` is a variable and `$a$` is `$(V U T)^{\ast}$,`